# Custom counter - format a \ref using Roman numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, roman-numerals

For example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\newcounter{cntAimNo}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\defAim}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{cntAimNo}%
   Aim~\Roman{cntAimNo}\label{#1}}

\newcommand{\refAim}[1]{Aim~\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}
\defAim{aim:foo} is to foo the bar. Later we will come back to \refAim{aim:foo}.

\end{document}
```

This renders the reference in arabic numbers:
[image]

How do I make `\refAim` use `\Roman` style instead?

Comment: Do `\renewcommand{\thecntAimNo}{\Roman{cntAimNo}` just after doing `\newcounter` and use `\thecntAimNo`.

Comment: @egreg perfect - why not post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The representation of a counter is obtained with the command `\the<counter>`.

In your case you want to represent the counter with Roman numerals.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\newcounter{cntAimNo}
\renewcommand{\thecntAimNo}{\Roman{cntAimNo} % default would be \arabic

\DeclareRobustCommand{\defAim}[1]{%
   \refstepcounter{cntAimNo}%
   Aim~\thecntAimNo\label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\refAim}[1]{Aim~\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\defAim{aim:foo} is to foo the bar. Later we will come back to \refAim{aim:foo}.

\end{document}
```